# Swift 3 comparable protocol

Tags: swift

Create a Name structure. A name has two parts a first name (also called a given
name or personal name) and a last name (family or surname). The Name structure should
implement the Comparable protocol.

I was trying with the following code but I don't know how to include the givenName, personalName,familyName and surName in the comparison

```
struct Name : Comparable {
let firstName : String
let lastName: String

init(firstName : String, lastName:String) {
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName=lastName
}
}func < (lhs: Name, rhs: Name) -> Bool {
return lhs.firstName < rhs.firstName && lhs.lastName < rhs.lastName  
}func == (lhs: Name, rhs: Name) -> Bool {
return lhs.firstName == rhs.firstName && lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName
}

let firstName = Name(firstName: "Paul", lastName: "Smith")
let givenName = Name(firstName: "Paul" , lastName: "Smithe")
let personalName = Name(firstName: "Paul", lastName: "Smith")
print (firstName == givenName)
```

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question and provide what you already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In America the default is to sort by `lastName` first, `firstName` second. You may change this if it's different in your country:

```
struct Name: Comparable {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String

    static func == (lhs: Name, rhs: Name) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.firstName == rhs.firstName) && (lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName)
    }

    // Provide the ordering for 2 names by comparing lastName first, for example:
    //      Jane Austen < Alan Smith
    //      Alan Smith  < John Smith
    static func < (lhs: Name, rhs:Name) -> Bool {
        if lhs.lastName != rhs.lastName {
            return lhs.lastName < rhs.lastName
        } else if lhs.firstName != rhs.firstName {
            return lhs.firstName < rhs.firstName
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should I just ignore the surName familyName personalName and givenName that are mentioned in the question?

Comment: What do you mean? Surname, last name and family name all mean the same thing in English: the part of your name which you inherit from your father. Similarly, first name = given name

Comment: I know but since they are mentioned in the question, I was thinking of enum  type

Comment: To me the question reads like it only ask for the `firstName` and the `lastName` properties

Comment: OK Thank YOU Jenny

Comment: An upvote and an answer mark is the most sincere thank :)'

Comment: How would you write this if lastName is optional? We cant use > < on String?. Would you use gurad let or? @Jenny

Answer (score 2):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, myprotocol{

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!

    func testfirst(info:String) {

        lbl1.text = info as String
    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

        @IBAction func btnshow(_ sender: UIButton)
    {

        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let svc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! secondViewController
        svc.delegate = self

        svc.str = text1.text!



        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(svc, animated: true)

    }
```

2)

```
protocol myprotocol {

    func testfirst(info:String)
}
```

3)

```
class secondViewController: UIViewController {


    var delegate : myprotocol?

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var txt2: UITextField!


    var str = String()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        lbl2.text = str
    }



    @IBAction func btn2(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if (delegate != nil)
        {
            let information:String = lbl2.text!+txt2.text!

            delegate?.testfirst(info: information)

            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
```